Crash on first build with targetSdk 34 and MediaProjection in Android 14
I am working on a Flutter app that records the screen using a Flutter package. The app was working fine when targeting targetSdkVersion 33, but after updating to targetSdkVersion 34 on Android 14, I started encountering an error.
Following the package documentation, I added the necessary permissions and service in AndroidManifest.xml:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />

<service
    android:name="com.foregroundservice.ForegroundService"
    android:foregroundServiceType="mediaProjection">
</service>

I also modified startForeground based on suggestions I found on StackOverflow:
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 34) {
    this.startForeground(
        1,
        notification,
        32) // ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
} else {
    this.startForeground(
        1,
        notification)
}

However, when I build the app for the first time, I get the following error, and the app forcefully closes:
E/AndroidRuntime(18946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(18946): Process: kr.roopre.recording, PID: 18946
E/AndroidRuntime(18946): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=333, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {kr.roopre.recording/kr.roopre.recording.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:6062)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:6101)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:67)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityTransactionItem.execute(ActivityTransactionItem.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:139)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:96)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2685)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8918)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:608)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103)
E/AndroidRuntime(18946): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Media projections require a foreground service of type ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PROJECTION

Interestingly, after rebuilding the app, this error does not occur, and everything works fine.
Can anyone help me resolve this issue?
